# $on taking $broadcast name as the first parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to

```
$emit('eventname', object, 'text');
```

```
on$('eventname', aObject, aText);
```

When I do this in the `$on` listener  `aObject = eventname` and `aText = object`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using this format - `$on('eventname', function(event, data){ /* ... */ }`

Comment: The `$on` method have the following structure `$on(eventName, listener)`, this listener is a `function(event, ...args)`.  Maybe you can get it done by reading the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks you are using incorrect syntax.. us below syntax.

```
 $scope.$emit('eventEmited', $scope.data);



$rootScope.$on('eventEmited', function (event, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on listener should implement a callback method, it should look like this...

```
$scope.$on("eventname", function(event, obj){ 
   // obj.aObject 
});
```

You should also pass your data as an object... This will make your code much easier to extend later if needed.

```
$emit('eventname', { aObject: object, aText: 'text'} );
```